# Assign Date Picker database value

Tags: c#, datepicker, webforms, telerik

I am working in a .net application where i should show a date in a box and if the date not correct i can update it.
I have use datePicker like below:

```
 <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" Text="" runat="server" Culture="en- 
  US"  MaxDate="2142-11-29" MinDate="2017-12-31">
 </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

which displays an empty box and a calendar to select a date. But i want the box to firstly be filled by a date value founded i the database. I tried

```
 RadDatePicker1.Text= dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"].ToString();
```

and also

```
RadDatePicker1.Value= dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"].ToString();
```

But they are giving errors and not working.

> 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker' does not contain a definition for
>   'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help how can i archive this? Thank you

Comment: I don't user Telerik components and I haven't written webforms in years so I can't actually answer your question. I'm just trying to improve your chances of getting an answer. One of these is to make sure you use [appropriate tags](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51306126/2) that way you get the right people viewing the question and not people like me who can't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following. Make sure add null and other required checks.

```
RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate = dt.Rows[0]["declaration_date"].ToString();
```